# Difference of String(contentsOf: URL).data(using: .utf8) vs. Data(contentsOf: URL)

Tags: swift

I have been playing with a json file in a playground and I've seen examples of reading the file like this:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try String(contentsOf: url).data(using: .utf8)
} catch {
    ...
}
```

And like this:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
    ...
}
```

Is there a difference in the data?  The only difference I see is the String data method is being formatted as UTF8 when read, where I am assuming the Data method is reading with a default format (UTF8 also??)?  I can't see a difference in the data, however, but just want to make sure.

Comment: Going to the string may result in error if data is not UTF8 but binary data. In the second case , code read contents of file as it is : it even can be a JOEG file. The error will happen in the json decoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `String(contentsOf: url)` tries to read *text* from that URL, whereas `Data(contentsOf: url)` reads the raw *bytes*.

Therefore, if the file at the URL is not a plain text file, `String(contentsOf: url)` could throw an error, whereas `Data(contentsOf: url)` would read it successfully.

Regarding the encoding, `String(contentsOf: url)` is undocumented, but from its [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/a33fda9b1aafae22ef1719cb6a8539758a64a13b/Sources/Foundation/NSStringAPI.swift#L409), we can see that it calls `NSString.init(contentsOf:usedEncoding:)`:

```
public init(
    contentsOf url: __shared URL
    ) throws {
    let ns = try NSString(contentsOf: url, usedEncoding: nil)
    self = String._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(ns)
}
```

[`NSString.init(contentsOf:usedEncoding:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414472-init?changes=lat_5__5) *is* documented:

> Returns an `NSString` object initialized by reading data from a given URL and returns by reference the encoding used to interpret the data.

So apparently the encoding is *guessed* (?) and returned by reference, which is then ignored by `String.init(contentsOf:)`, as it passed `nil` for the `usedEncoding` parameter.

This means that for some non-UTF-8 files, there is a chance of `String(contentsOf:)` guessing the correct encoding, and then `data(using: .utf8)` encodes the string to UTF-8 bytes, making the rest of your code work. If you had used `Data(contentsOf:)`, you would be reading in the wrong encoding, and though it wouldn't throw an error, the JSON-parsing code later down the line probably would.

That said, JSON is supposed to be exchanged in UTF-8 (See [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1)), so an error when you read a non-UTF-8 file is probably *desired*.

So basically, if we are choosing between these two options, just use `Data(contentsOf:)`. It's simpler and less typing. You don't need to worry about thing like wrong encodings, or that the file is not plain text. If anything like that happens, it is not JSON, and the `JSONDecoder` later down the line would throw.